# Properties reference for hibernate in persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, persistence.xml

Does anyone know a link, post, book or something else where are explained and nominalized all properties that you need and can use in persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The JPA 2.0 supported properties (`javax.persistence.*`) can be found in [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Vendor-specific properties can be found in appropriate vendor documentation:

- [Hibernate properties (`hibernate.*`)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)
- [EclipseLink properties (`eclipselink.*`)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm)

Answer (score 7):

Full list of properties, that hibernate uses, you can find in class

```
org\hibernate\cfg\Environment.java
```

in `Hibernate` distribution.

[**Javadoc here**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are actually 2 sources:

- `org.hibernate.jpa.AvailableSettings`. Cf. javadoc:  "Defines the available HEM settings, both JPA-defined as well as Hibernate-specific. NOTE : Does *not* include {@link org.hibernate.cfg.Environment} values."
- `org.hibernate.cfg.Environment`