# What's the meaning of properties of persistence.xml file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm studying the hibernate framework, and I would like to know where can I get information about de properties that we need to include in the file persistence.xml

I search about the propertie provider, but I don't get specific information, sombody help me :D

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="tarefas">
    <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- entidade mapeada -->
    <properties>
        <!-- dados da conexao -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <!-- propriedades do hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Suppose this post may be helpful to you.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html)       [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/02/jpa-tutorial.html)

Comment: @MateusLeal can you take a look at my answer and let me know if you need any more clarification? If not then can you please accept my answer if you think this answer is sufficiently reasonable? thanks

Comment: See also [Properties reference for hibernate in persistence.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324821/properties-reference-for-hibernate-in-persistence-xml).

Answer (score 4):

I found this in the book that I read to learn Spring and Hibernate. The book name is *Professional Java for Web Applications* written by *Nicholas S. Williams*. I think this will be helpful for many people.

> Creating the Persistence Configuration:
>
> To use the entities you create, you must define a persistence unit. Doing so is simple. Create a
>   persistence.xml file not dissimilar from a deployment descriptor, but with far fewer options
>   to worry about. The root element of a persistence configuration file is `<persistence>`. This
>   element may contain one or more `<persistence-unit>` elements. No other elements are
>   within `<persistence>`. `<persistence-unit>` has two attributes: name specifies the name of
>   the persistence unit and transaction-type indicates whether this persistence unit uses Java
>   Transaction API (JTA) transactions or standard local transactions.
>   You must specify a name, which is how you locate the persistence unit in code. If not specified,
>   transaction-type defaults to JTA in a Java EE application server and RESOURCE_LOCAL in a Java
>   SE environment or simple Servlet container. However, to prevent unexpected behavior it’s best to
>   always set this value explicitly instead of relying on a default value.
>   `<persistence-unit>` contains the following inner elements. None of them are required (so
>   `<persistence-unit>` may be empty); however, you must specify whichever elements you use in the
>   following order:
>
> - `<description>` contains a useful description for this persistence unit. Although it makes
>     reading the persistence file easier, it has no semantic value.
> - `<provider>` specifies the fully qualified class name of the javax.persistence.spi
>     .PersistenceProvider implementation used for this persistence unit. By default, when you
>     look up the persistence unit, the API will use the first JPA provider on the classpath. You
>     can include this element to mandate a specific JPA provider.
> - You can use either `<jta-data-source>` or `<non-jta-data-source>` (but not both) to
>     use a JNDI DataSource resource. You may use `<jta-data-source>` only if
>     transaction-type is JTA; likewise you may use `<non-jta-data-source>` only
>     if transaction-type is RESOURCE_LOCAL. Specifying a DataSource causes the persistence
>     unit to use that DataSource for all entity operations.
> - `<mapping-file>` specifies the classpath-relative path to an XML mapping file. If you don’t
>     specify any `<mapping-file>`, the provider looks for orm.xml. You may specify multiple
>     `<mapping-file>` elements to use multiple mapping files.
> - You can use one or more `<jar-file>` elements to specify a JAR file or JAR files that the
>     JPA provider should scan for mapping-annotated entities. Any @Entity, @Embeddable,
>     @javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass, or @javax.persistence.Converter classes
>     found are added to the persistence unit.
> - You can use one or more `<class>` elements to indicate specific @Entity, @Embeddable,
>     @MappedSuperclass, or @Converter classes that should be added to the persistence unit.
>     You must annotate the class or classes with JPA annotations.
> - Using `<exclude-unlisted-classes />` or `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` indicates that the provider should ignore classes not
>     specified with `<jar-file>` or `<class>`. Omitting `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` or using
>     `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` causes the JPA
>     provider to scan the classpath location of the persistence file for JPA-annotated classes. If
>     persistence.xml is located in a JAR file, that JAR file (and only that JAR file) is scanned
>     for classes. If persistence.xml is located in a directory-based classpath location (such as /
>     WEB-INF/classes), that directory (and only that directory) is scanned for classes. Prior to
>     Hibernate 4.3.0 and Spring Framework 3.2.5, specifying this element with the value false
>     was incorrectly interpreted as true.
> - `<shared-cache-mode>` indicates how entities are cached in the persistence unit (if the JPA
>     provider supports caching, which is optional). NONE disables caching, whereas ALL enables
>     caching for all entities. ENABLE_SELECTIVE means that only entities annotated @javax
>     .persistence.Cacheable or @Cacheable(true) (or marked as cacheable in orm.xml)
>     are cached. DISABLE_SELECTIVE results in caching of all entities except those annotated
>     @Cacheable(false) (or marked as non-cacheable in orm.xml). The default value,
>     UNSPECIFIED, means that the JPA provider decides what the effective default is. Hibernate
>     ORM defaults to ENABLE_SELECTIVE, but relying on this is not portable.
> - `<validation-mode>` indicates if and how Bean Validation should be applied to entities.
>     NONE means that Bean Validation is not enabled, whereas CALLBACK makes the provider
>     validate all entities on insert, update, and delete. AUTO has an effective value of CALLBACK
>     if a Bean Validation provider exists on the classpath and an effective value of NONE if no
>     Bean Validation provider exists on the classpath. If you enable validation, the JPA provider
>     configures a new Validator to validate your entities. If you have configured a special
>     Spring Framework Validator with your custom localized error codes, the JPA provider
>     ignores it. As such, it’s best to set the validation mode to NONE and use Bean Validation
>     before your persistence layer is invoked.
> - `<properties>` provides a way to specify other JPA properties, including standard JPA
>     properties (such as JDBC connection string, username, and password, or schema generation
>     settings) as well as provider-specific properties (such as Hibernate settings). You specify
>     one or more properties using nested  elements, each with a name and value
>     attribute.

*`Nicholas S. Williams, Professional Java for Web Applications, (Indianapolis, Indiana: John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 2014), pg 584-585`*

Comment: also rfer the JPA Spec [link](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: @fararzdurrani (+1)