# What properties does persistence-unit have in apache openjpa?

Tags: java, jpa, properties

I have not found any good documentation about it.

Example of *persistence-unit* in *persistence.xml*:

```
<persistence-unit name="DataLayer"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>myNonJtaDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property
            name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="create" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=""/>
        <property name="" value=""/>
        <property name="" value=""/>
        <property name="" value=""/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I found some like: *javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action*, etc., but I am looking for a (full?) list of "names" of those properties and maybe their possible values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properties reference for hibernate in persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324821/properties-reference-for-hibernate-in-persistence-xml)

Comment: Yes, but also no, because i was looking for apache openjpa and i found it here: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.0.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_conf_openjpa.html Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reference for persistence properties for JPA 2.X:
https://www.developer.com/java/ent/standard-persistence-properties-in-jpa-2.html

This is reference for openjpa: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.0.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_conf_openjpa.html

And here are also properties for Hibernate and EclipseLink: [Properties reference for hibernate in persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324821/properties-reference-for-hibernate-in-persistence-xml)